# how to get date of my localtime like 2020-03-11T02:59 with javascript

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

i want to get my country date like this `2020-03-11T02:59` i try to JSON and toISOString but it give me the hours does not true

Comment: do you mean your local time?

Comment: yes my localtime

Comment: i'm not sure what you mean about the hours. `toISOString` should be enough...

Comment: @DanielA.White I believe he is saying that it's not giving him his local time zone, but that he is getting UTC.  This answer may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10087819/convert-date-to-another-timezone-in-javascript

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can change the timezone with the offset at the end of the date string (e.g. -05:00).

And then create the date string you want using get functions.

You will need to pad the month, day, hour and minutes. However, the .get (eg `.getMonth`) functions return numbers, so you will also have to convert them to strings.

For example: `event.getMonth().toString().padStart(2,0);`

`event` is your date object.

`.getMonth()` returns the numeric value of the month of your date object

`.toString()` converts that number to a string value

`.padStart(2,0)` will add zeros to the front of the string if it is less than 2 characters.

```js
// Set the date with timezone offset
let event = new Date("2020-03-11T02:59:00-08:00");

// Format your string
let newEvent = `${event.getFullYear()}-${event.getMonth().toString().padStart(2,0)}-${event.getDate().toString().padStart(2,0)}T${event.getHours().toString().padStart(2,0)}:${event.getMinutes().toString().padStart(2,0)}`;

console.log(newEvent);
```

Comment: This doesn't produce the format the OP wants.

Comment: @RobG You are right. I should have formatted it.